# SPSS 26: How to calculate the absolute differences in scores from repeated measunrements in order to create cumulative frequency tables

Tags: spss

I am working with SPSS 26 and I have some trouble finding out which functions to use...

I have scores from repeated measurements (9 setups with each 3 stimulus types á 10 scores ) and need to calculate the absolute differences in scores in order to create cumulative frequency tables. The whole thing is about test-retest variability of the scores obtained with the instrument. The main goal is to be able to say that e.g. XX % of the scores for setup X and stimulus type X were within X points. Sorry, I hope that is somehow understandable :) I APPRECIATE ANY HELP I CAN GET I AM TERRIBLE AT THIS!

Comment: is this a programming question?  Just making sure.

Comment: Please edit your post to add some example data and expected results for the example. Also add any code you've already tried. This will help us understand what you're trying to do so we can help you code it.